# largest subarray of consecutive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm trying to find the largest subarray of consecutive numbers in an array. 
Take the following for example
{34,35,36,88,90,91,92,93}
I need the sub array {90,91,92,93} but I can't seem to get how.
Any help appreciated.I've done my search and only have found the largest sum problem or the length of the largest subarray without the subarray itself.
By the way I'm working on Java.

Comment: The thing is that this is part of a larger problem so I don't think what I've done is of much relevance.

Comment: If you have a solution for the length, all you need is an extra variable to keep track of the start index.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array. Keep a note of the 'current best' sub-array of consecutive values (which seems like a start and end index) and a 'current actual' (i.e. one which the current index is a part of). And then for each index work out what the 'current actual' is (also a start/end index) - if the value at index 'i' is not consecutive to the previous 'i' then it's the start of a new one, otherwise it's a new end of the old one. If the 'current actual' then turns out to be longer than the current best then replace the current best with the current actual. When you get to the end of the array return whatever's 'current best'. The only question then is how to initialise 'current best', which is pretty easy, it starts at index 0 and ends at index 0.